# Windows Phone - Increment a value

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

How can I increment a value per second, when I passed it from another page?

Here is some code , where I get the value from the previous page + I added the Timer.

The Problem is that the EventHandler that has to been created for the Tick, can t be set to OnNavigatedTo.

```
    public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.1)   };


    public Page1()
    {

            InitializeComponent();

            this.timer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnNavigatedTo);
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(OnNavigatedTo);


    }



    private void ButtonToPage1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App app = Application.Current as App;
        MessageBox.Show(app.storeValue);
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string QueryStr = "";
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("myNumber", out QueryStr);
        int test = (int.Parse(QueryStr));

    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried with `System.Timers.Timer(Double interval)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried this. But the problem is that i can t increment it, because for a tick i need a event (or method). OnNavigatedTo i can t use for this. I tried it with this: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Implement_timers_in_Windows_Phone

Comment: What do you mean you need an event? Just use a lambda. And even aside from that, there's no reason an event shouldn't work.

Comment: @alexdagee: Create the timer and its tick method that will increment the value of the `test` variable. Then in the `OnNavigatedTo` method set the value of `test` and start the timer. Use the tutorial that you provided to see how to do this. Post your code with this attempt if you run into problems.

Comment: added it to my post ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
DispatcherTimer tmr;
int test;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string QueryStr = "";
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("myNumber", out QueryStr);
    test = (int.Parse(QueryStr));
    LoadTimer();
}

public void LoadTimer()
{
    tmr = new DispatcherTimer();
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        tmr.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        tmr.Tick += tmr_Tick;
        tmr.Start();
    });
}

void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test++;
    TextBlock.Text = test.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. it works, but it doesn t use the value i got from the previous page ;)

Comment: it does.. see the code.. i m passing the value of QueryStr to test variable that you got from querystring

Comment: mhh do you tested it on a wp? I just tested it and it starts with 1. Maybe the "int test" in the beginning is a problem, because it sets the value to 0?

Comment: maybe one more question. on every tick, it should add itself as number. so something like i typed in 5 and on every second it goes five up. how can i solve this? i can t write test+test.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear why you can't just follow the tutorial linked in your comment. I guess you misunderstand it and tried to handle `Tick` event using `OnNavigatedTo()` method. Yes, that won't work and you aren't supposed to do so.

You're supposed to simply attach event handler method in `OnNavigatedTo` :

```
private int myNumber;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string QueryStr = "";
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("myNumber", out QueryStr);
    myNumber = (int.Parse(QueryStr));

    DispatcherTimer newTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    newTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    //attach event handler method for Tick event
    newTimer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
    //or attach anonymous method so you don't need OnTimerTick() method :
    //newTimer.Tick += (o, e) => { myNumber++; };
    newTimer.Start();
}

void OnTimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    myNumber++;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. where can i display the incrementing value in a textblock? in the on navigatedto or the ontimertick?

Comment: OnTimerTick so displayed value always up to date